# An analog of Chinese remainder theorem using field extensions

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field, intuition, irreducible-polynomials, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm trying to find number systems with specific properties.  If we suppose that $p(x)$, a polynomial in $x$ is irreducible over the finite field with $q$ elements, $q$ prime, I have a few questions.

I believe that we can then use this irreducible polynomial to construct a finite field of size $q^n$ if $n$ is the degree of the polynomial.  I want to make sure that I know when I can do this, so that's my first question: "When can I construct this field?"

Now, assuming that we can construct a finite field of size $p^n$ elements in the fashion above, I'm interested in using an analog of Chinese remainder theorem on it.  The idea is now to use a smaller prime $r$ such that the polynomial *does* reduce over $r$.  The next idea is that if I then use enough primes $r_1$, $r_2$, $r_3$, \dots that I can represent this "number" exactly.  In other words, if the number is $c_1 s_1 + c_2 s_2 + \dots$, where $s_1$ and $s_2$ are roots of the polynomial, and $c_1$ and $c_2$ are non-negative integers, I can possibly recover the exact value of the number using enough primes.  Is this possible?

**CLARIFICATION**

We pick one "exact" polynomial $p(x)$, whose exact value is irreducible modulo $q$, but reducible modulo the smaller primes $r_1$, $r_2$, $\dots$.

**COMPLETE EXAMPLE**

Here's one complete example; let me know if you would like more.

Let $p(x) = 6 x^3 + 2 x + 3$.

Then, we have, according to Mathematica 11:

$$p(x) \equiv 6 (7 + 9 x + x^3) \bmod 13$$
$$p(x) \equiv 6 (3+x)(9+x)(10+x) \bmod 11$$
$$p(x) \equiv 6 (2+x)(2+5x+x^2) \bmod 7$$
$$p(x) \equiv (1+x^2)(3+x) \bmod 5$$

It's not perfect, but it should do.

Then we let $q = 13$, our largest prime.  Note that the polynomial is irreducible modulo $13$.

Now, modulo $11$ is our best example, it has 3 roots: -3, -9, and -10, up to a reversal of the negative sign.

Now the idea is to take equivalence classes, modulo primes, using polynomials and/or field extensions.  If we have

$$2 \text{(root 1)} + 3 \text{(root 2)} + 1 \text{(root 3)} \bmod 13$$

Where the roots are taken from $p(x)$, we can rewrite this as:

$$\text{value 1} \equiv 2 \underbrace{(-3)}_{\text{root 1}} + 3 \underbrace{(-9)}_{\text{root 2}} + 1 \underbrace{(-10)}_{\text{root 3}} \bmod 11$$

Furthermore, we can use two more equations to permute the roots and recover the values:

$$\text{value 2} \equiv 2 \underbrace{(-9)}_{\text{root 2}} + 3 \underbrace{(-10)}_{\text{root 3}} + 1\underbrace{(-3)}_{\text{root 1}} \bmod 11$$

$$\text{value 3} \equiv 2 \underbrace{(-10)}_{\text{root 3}} + 3\underbrace{(-3)}_{\text{root 1}} + 1 \underbrace{(-9)}_{\text{root 2}} \bmod 11$$

We can now use linear algebra to recover the coefficients of the roots, modulo $11$.

Assuming that we can do similar for $5$ and $7$, we can do calculations and recover the *exact* values of each root coefficient up to $5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 = 385$.  We should be able to use this for larger coefficients and polynomials, similarly.

**QUESTIONS**

My main question is "does this construction work?", and when can I use it?

Comment: This is not clear.  If your polynomial is defined over $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ what does it mean to reduce it "over $r$" for some other prime $r$?  Consider, say, $p(x)=x^2+1$ over $\mathbb F_7$.  It is irreducible.  now $x^2+1$ is also irreducible over $\mathbb F_3$ but $x^2+8$ is reducible, it equals $(x+1)(x-1)\pmod 3$.  But $\pmod 7$ $x^2+1$ and $x^2+8$ are the same polynomial.  So is $p(x)$ reducible over $\mathbb F_3$ or not?

Comment: @lulu: Using your example, we pick one "exact" polynomial.  We would also pick one large prime $q$, and many smaller primes $r_1$, $r_2$, $\dots$.  We would pick one polynomial that is irreducible modulo $q$ and reducible modulo all of the $r$'s.  In your example, we would pick $x^2+8$, but not $x^2+1$, because $x^2 + 8$ is reducible modulo 3.  To restate all of this: the first step is to find an "exact" polynomial that is irreducible modulo a large prime $q$, and reducible modulo $r$. Just because $x^2 + 1$ and $x^2 + 8$ are equivalent modulo $7$, they are not _equal_.

Comment: They are equal over $\mathbb F_7$.  I don't know what it means to pick one "exact" polynomial.  As a general rule, any construction that depends on a list of ad hoc choices is going to be hard to generalize...if you have a complete example of the phenomenon you want to study you should include it in your post.

Comment: @lulu:  I will try to include a complete example to explain.  I'll let you know when it's done... sorry for the confusion, but thanks for your interest.

Comment: @lulu:  I've added an example, and I'm really hoping it makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, still not getting.  I get that you mean to start with a polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$.  That helps.  But...if I know $p(x)$ factors completely $\pmod {11}$ then I know $p(x)\pmod  {11}$ up to a constant.  That does not determine $p(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$, clearly.  No finite list of primes can do that...you could always add any  polynomial whose coefficients were divisible by the product of those primes.  So...what is the goal?

Comment: @lulu: You may understand it better than you think.  The goal is to find a way to represent a number with a large multiplicative order as a very small number.  The use of the polynomial is simply to create field extensions, so I can extend a number modulo $q$ to a number in a finite field with $q^n$ numbers.  Then I can represent a number with a large multiplicative order as a small number.  In other words, I'm really just using $p(x)$ as a vehicle to allow me to use these number systems.  Then the hope is that it is reducible modulo all primes smaller than $q$.

Comment: @lulu:  From what you're saying, it seems like finding a polynomial that works should not be that difficult, since I can always make it larger so that it works modulo all primes that I'm working with.

Comment: @lulu:  It seems that I can then create any polynomial I want modulo $r$, a smaller prime than $q$, so that I can make its' roots give unique values given the linear algebra technique I use in the example.

Comment: Just to be clear:  when you say "reducible" you appear to mean "fully reducible".  I.e. you want it to factor completely into linear terms.  That seems to  me to be a very strong requirement, if the degree is high.  If the degree is small I expect you can do it.

Comment: @lulu: Yes, I mean "fully reducible".  I'm also looking for the lowest degree polynomial that fits.  I think you know what I'm looking for now.  I'm just trying to find a way that we can guarantee that we can find a polynomial that fits the requirements, or something that's doable.

Comment: Well, I'd try some examples to see.  Not quadratics...that's too easy.  Take degree $5$ or so.  Easy to find irreducible examples.  $x^5+2$ is irreducible $\pmod {11}$, say.  Now find polynomials equivalent to that $\pmod {11}$ which factor fully modulo $3,5,7$.  Should be possible, but I don't suppose it's easy.  As with the CRT, I'd go layer by layer.  Start with $p=7$, then you'll get a polynomial $\pmod {77}$ and you can search for an example which is fully reducible $\pmod 5$, and so on.  $x^5+35$ is fully reducible $\pmod 7$ for instance, though maybe this is a bad example.

Comment: That particular example is easy, which maybe means I started with a poor choice.  All you need is to use CRT to solve $a\equiv 2 \pmod {11}, a\equiv 0 \pmod 7, a\equiv 0\pmod 5, a\equiv 0 \pmod 3$. $a=420$ works. Then $x^5+420$ has the desired property.

Comment: Using the CRT we see that we can always do this...pick any fully reducible polynomials you like (of fixed degree) modulo $p_1,p_2, \cdots, p_n$ and one irreducible modulo $p_{n+1}$.  Then use CRT to find a single polynomial of that degree with coefficients congruent to each of the desired polynomials' coefficients.  But...so what?  Seems too cheap to have much content.

Comment: @lulu: The trick was to find a polynomial that's small but fits all of the criterion...  Anyways, I'm working on applying it to integer multiplication algorithms.  The second trick seems to be that multiple coefficients in a DFT map to essentially the same multiplier.  Anyways, I'm still working on it.

Comment: @lulu:  You can look at my crappy paper on using lookup tables for integer multiplication at https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.07124  I'm trying to find a way to use lookup tables, combined with small numbers, to do integer multiplication faster.

Comment: @lulu:  The "second trick" really seems like it will work.  You have an element with multiplicative order $q^n$ modulo $q$, but modulo $r$ for the right $r$, it will have order only $r$.  Of course, it needs to be a principal root of unity.  But then you can do the DFT in time $O(r^2)$, which is much less time than $(q^n) \log{(q^n)}$.  So you only have to do a few DFTs which can be done very quickly.  This should work, and I thank you for talking me through this!

Comment: Where do these "roots" live? In the splitting field of the polynomial you started with? They absolutely cannot be treated as elements of $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ for in that field every element is divisible by all the smaller primes $r_1,r_2,\ldots$.

Comment: I guess you want to look at this in the ring of integer $\mathcal{O}_K$ of the splitting field $K$ of the polynomial you started with. Then all the prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$ above $p$ have inertia degree equal to the degree of the polynomial. There is no ramification, so you will only have a single prime ideal, if the Galois group is cyclic. Anyway, then the roots will have a clear identity in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: By Chebotarev's density theorem there will be infinitely many primes $r$ such that the polynomial splits completely into linear factors modulo $r$. The fraction of such primes is asymptotically determined by the size of the Galois group. Yeah, if you have an integral basis of $K$ (=a $\Bbb{Z}$-basis of $\mathcal{O}_K$, **and** have some kind of bounds on the size of the coordinates of the zeros, then knowing those coordinates modulo enough many primes will let you determine the coefficients. But, there is the problem of determining which root modulo $r$ corresponds to which zero.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  I'm having a hard time following, because I don't really know "ideals", "inertia degree", "ramification", and I'm shaky with Galois group.  It sounds like there is a chance that this could work.  I'm really sorry that I don't have enough background...  I'm trying to change that.  I do realize that there's the problem of determining which roots correspond to the zeros, but I don't have a solution for that yet.  I would certainly accept an answer if you could solve these problems, and explain it so I could understand it.  I forgot about matching the roots.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I'm still thinking in terms of which root modulo $r$ corresponds to which zero.  One thought is just to go through every possible combination modulo all the primes we use to find the $r$'s we're looking for, if this makes sense - I call this the avoidance method.  As long as we can somehow get the roots to match up, we can probably do the DFT in linear time.  We may require a ton of preprocessing time, but we can do it.